# How to create a key indexed array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a blank array similar like: `WO_Attribute: [] (0)`

I also have key : **363270** and

> array: { wosetid: "363612", woattrvalueid: 212122, woattrvalue:
>   "testing", woattrid: 6842 }

How can I create similar array as follows:

```
"WO_Attribute": {
    "363270": [
        {
            "wosetid": 363270,
            "woattrvalueid": 5160601,
            "woattrvalue": "testing",
            "woattrid": 1602
        }
    ]
}
```

I used the following method but its not working if WO_Attribute is blank array:

```
let WO_Attribute = [];
let resArr = [];
let resVal = { 
    wosetid: "363612", 
    woattrvalueid: 212122, 
    woattrvalue: "testing", 
    woattrid: 6842 
};

resArr.push(resVal);

WO_Attribute[key] = resArr;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the `WO_Attribute` to an object like this.

```
let WO_Attribute = {};
WO_Attribute["363270"] = resArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) to iterate through the array and create the object you want.

```js
const data = [{
  "wosetid": 363270,
  "woattrvalueid": 5160601,
  "woattrvalue": "testing",
  "woattrid": 1602
}, {
  "wosetid": 312485,
  "woattrvalueid": 5160602,
  "woattrvalue": "testing2",
  "woattrid": 1603
}];
const result = data.reduce((o, v) => { o[v.wosetid] = v; return o; }, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`WO_Attribute` is an `Object` and not an `Array`.

> The difference between Objects and Arrays in javascript is that 
>   objects are key value pairs where keys can be strings or numbers and array is an
>   ordered set of elements where keys are ordered by numeric values
>   starting from 0. So arrays are also objects with some limitations and some additional array specific properties and methods

```
let WO_Attribute = {}; //Initialize WO_Attribute as an empty object.


let resVal = {
                "wosetid": 363270,
                "woattrvalueid": 5160601,
                "woattrvalue": "testing",
                "woattrid": 1602
            }

/*add a property to the object with key '363270' and empty array as value.*/
WO_Attribute['363270'] = []; 

/*push the data object to the array*/
WO_Attribute[resVal.wosetid].push(resVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

`WO_Attribute`  need to be an object instead of array

```js
let WO_Attribute = {};
let key = "363270";
let resArr = [];

let resVal = {
  wosetid: "363612",
  woattrvalueid: 212122,
  woattrvalue: "testing",
  woattrid: 6842
};

resArr.push(resVal);

WO_Attribute[key] = resArr;
console.log(WO_Attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object instead of Array, and if you'd like to iterate it you can use `Object.keys` or `Object.values` methods to go through its keys or values:

```js
let WO_Attribute = {};

WO_Attribute['some_key_1'] = 'Some Value 1';
WO_Attribute['some_key_2'] = 'Some Value 2';

Object.keys(WO_Attribute).forEach(key => {
  console.log(WO_Attribute[key]);
  // some other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var data = [{ wosetid: 363270, woattrvalueid: 5160601, woattrvalue: "testing", woattrid: 1602 }, { wosetid: 312485, woattrvalueid: 5160602, woattrvalue: "testing2", woattrid: 1603 }],
    result = Object.assign(...data.map(o => ({ [o.wosetid]: o })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```